# how to stop a setInterval after I got my server response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to stop my `setInterval()` call. The best would be to identify whenever my AJAX request is fulfilled. So, If I got my AJAX GET response, then `clearinterval()`.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#post-form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/send',
    data: {
      room_name: $('#room_name').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //alert(data)
    }
  });

  $(document).ready(function com() {

    loop = setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/trafic",
        success: function check(response) {
          //SOME CODE//

        },
        error: function(response) {
          //SOME CODE//
        }
      });
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(clearInterval(loop), 10000);

  })
});
```

I tried to set a timeout, but it is very imprecise as it may take longer/shorter than the delay. So I would need something like `if GET successful {clear interval()}`

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. When do you want to clear the interval?

Comment: I want to clear the interval after receiving the get response. Which is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `clearInterval()` call into the `success` callback of the AJAX call. You'll also need to move the `loop` interval higher up in your code so that it can be referenced from the `success` callback.

I'm also not sure why the `loop` interval is wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` call, because you can be assured that the document is ready if it is submitted. Also, the variable `loop` is awfully ambiguous. Try using the name of the API endpoint instead, like `traffic`.

Try this code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#post-form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const traffic = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/trafic",
      success: function check(response) {
        clearInterval(traffic);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        //SOME CODE//
      }
    });
  }, 1000);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/send',
    data: {
      room_name: $('#room_name').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // some code
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ty Michael,  However I need to clearInterval on GET success. Not on POST success. I want to stop my setintervaal GET Request when I receive the data from my backend server so it does not send it 60 times.

Comment: @mkch Ah I see now. I've edited my answer. It should now work.

Comment: @mkch Does my updated code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask you first why did you use setInterval on this HTTP request ? You are probably using more computation power than you need.

You should probably make the request async (e.g https://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax)

If you want to wait for an event to appear, you may want to have a look at web sockets (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/websockets/index.htm)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).